# Rx.NET: Take until specified count or timer elapsed

Tags: c#, linq, system.reactive

I have a solution for receiving `Observable` notifications until specified count arrived **or** time threshold elapsed. Also, I need to know which one happened.

Wondering if there is a simpler way (maybe other than `GroupByUntil`) to achieve this functionality

```
_values.
.GroupByUntil(_ => true,
              i => Observable.Timer(Threshold, _scheduler)
                             .Amb(i.Buffer(SpecifiedCount).Select(_ => SpecifiedCount)))
// this is for figuring out which one happened: interval elapsed or count filled
.SelectMany(g => g.Count())
// Let's say if count filled first, call Foo()
.Where( i => i == SpecifiedCount ) 
.Subscribe( _ => Foo() )
```

Comment: Both Buffer and Window accept either count or TimeSpan, or both. Have you tried them?

Comment: I now have and they functionality differs from the `GroupByUntil` solution. Trying to figure out why.

Comment: What functionality *do* you want? What is different?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos after testing with trivial `Observables`, I now believe the differing functionality comes from my test environment and/or misusage of `TestScheduler`. I will close this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for [Observable.Buffer Method (IObservable, TimeSpan, Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229200(v=vs.103).aspx)? According to the docs

> Indicates each element of an observable sequence into a buffer that’s sent out when either it’s full or a given amount of time has elapsed.

You should be able to write:

```
var myObservable=_values.Buffer(Threshold,SpecifiedCount);
```

There's a similar overload for [Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228991(v=vs.103).aspx) as well.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much what I want. There's a slight alteration to `GroupByUntil` functionality in some cases. Sometimes the first notification does not get buffered and the first buffer actually takes `SpecifiedCount + 1` of notifications to send out. Can you think of a reason why this would happen?

Comment: Btw, this happens while running it on `TestScheduler`, using the overload `Buffer(IObservable, TimeSpan, int, IScheduler )`